# Необходимо проверить txt файл на совпадение цифр. Python

Tags: python, строки

Есть файл user.txt в нем содержится набор цифр:

- 111
- 222
- 333
- 444
- 555

Нужно следующее: Пользователь вводит число, к примеру 333, если число 333 содержатся в файле user.txt то оно его не записывает, а если такого числа нет? он его записывает в конец строки.

Вот код который пытался написать, но он не правильный.

```
 number(chislo) 
 f = open("user.txt", 'a+')
 if f == number:
    f.close()
 else:
    f.write(number) + '\n')
```

Comment: Конечно, неправильный. ``number(chislo)``  - что делает эта строчка? ``f == number`` - ``f`` у вас - объект файла, а не текст из этого файли и тем более не отдельная строчка. Вам нужно взять учебник и почитать, как читать из текстовых файлов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно как-то так, если учитывать, что все ваши числа разделены пробелами или записаны с новой строчки:

```
with open("test.txt", mode="r+") as f:
    text = f.read()
    numbers_list = [int(x) for x in text.split()]
    num = int(input("Вводим искомое число: "))
    if num in numbers_list:
        print("Такое число есть")
    else:
        print("Такого числа нет, записываю")
        f.write(' ' + f"{num}")  # или ('\n' + f"{num}"), если каждое число с новой строки необходимо записать
```

Comment: если ввести 33, а в файле есть строчка 333, а строчки 33 нет, то будет неправильное поведение

Comment: Смотри. Чуть переделал. Но всё равно добавляет один и тот же номер.
message.chat.id - получение от пользователя его id, он только в srt

*****

    with open("test.txt", "a+") as f:
        text = f.read()
        numbers_list = [int(x) for x in text.split()]
        num = str(message.chat.id)
        if num in numbers_list:
            print("Такое число есть")
        else:
            print("Такого числа нет, записываю")
            f.write((num) + '\n')  # запись в файл

Comment: @Дмитрий, если сделаешь num = int(message.chat.id), тогда будет отлавливать одинаковые. Ты сравниваешь числа и строку, язык справедливо воспринимает их за разные объекты. И с каждым запуском программы, все элементы будут преобразовываться в int. Почему message.chat.id нельзя преобразовать в int?

Comment: Напиши мне пожалуйста в телеграмме, я всё подробно напишу @kazudji